# Question on Inner Products and Symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Determine if the following statement is true or false: There is no inner product on $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ w.r.t. which the differentiation map $T: P_3(\mathbb{R})\to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(f)=f'$ is symmetric.

For this question I try to assume there is an inner product and then prove no such inner products and this is because the differentiation map is not surjective. But I am not sure if I have the correct idea.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $(-,-)$ is any inner product over $P_3(\mathbb{R})$. Calculate $(x, T(1))$ and $(T(x), 1)$ and show that $(x,T(1))\neq (T(x),1)$. What is the conclusion?

Comment: Thank you so much!